# Add a new sheet using Input Box, check existing sheet names and invalid sheet names

Tags: vba, excel

Im new to VBA but i need to do something with it. I want to make input box that add a new sheet with specific name. somehow i can make it after some searching over the forum. here are the steps that i want to do, but i cant make it completely done.

- make input box that ask a name of new sheet (it's done).
- when the name of sheet is already available then a msg box appear
  that it can't make a new sheet but when the opposite happen then a
  new sheet is made (it's done too).
- the last is i want to make when the input box is blank a new msg box
  appear and ask to enter different name (this i can't do).

Here's the code im using so far

```
Public Sub CariSheet()
Dim SheetName As String
Dim shExists As Boolean

Do

SheetName = InputBox("Write the name of sheet", "Add Sheet")
If NamaSheet <> "" Then

shExists = SheetExists(SheetName)
If Not shExists Then

Worksheets.Add(After:=Worksheets(Worksheets.Count)).Name = SheetName
MsgBox "The sheet " & (SheetName) & " is successfuly made", , "Result"
Else

MsgBox "The name is already exist, please enter a new name", vbOKOnly + vbInformation, "Name"

End If
End If
Loop Until Not shExists Or SheetName = ""
End Sub

Private Function SheetExists(ByVal SheetName As String, _
Optional ByVal wb As Workbook)

If wb Is Nothing Then Set wb = ActiveWorkbook
On Error Resume Next
SheetExists = Not wb.Worksheets(SheetName) Is Nothing

End Function
```

any help will be appreciated, thanks in advance for your attention. ah and sorry for my bad english.

Comment: What *precisely* is the problem?

Comment: @jeeped i can't make the input box shows a msg box that blank isn't the right input.
sorry i can't arrange it into a good statement due to my bad english.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Check if this code helps you:

Just added **Else part** for you Main If condition where you check **If Sheetname is not blank**.

Also, You can also uncomment my line **Exit Sub** if you want to exit subroutine in case of blank input box.

```
Public Sub CariSheet()
Dim SheetName As String
Dim shExists As Boolean

Do

SheetName = InputBox("Write the name of sheet", "Add Sheet")
If SheetName <> "" Then
shExists = SheetExists(SheetName)
    If Not shExists Then    
        Worksheets.Add(After:=Worksheets(Worksheets.Count)).Name = SheetName
        MsgBox "The sheet " & (SheetName) & " is successfuly made", , "Result"
    Else
        MsgBox "The name is already exist, please enter a new name", vbOKOnly + vbInformation, "Name"
    End If
Else
    MsgBox "Please enter a sheet name.", vbOKOnly + vbInformation, "Warning"
'Exit Sub
End If
Loop Until Not shExists Or SheetName = ""
End Sub
```

Comment: yeah i tried it before, but it didn't worked out, but thanks for your help. i really appreciate it..

Comment: im a bit confused, im sure i tried it before but it didn't worked out then i use your code it works out fine..

Answer (score 4):

This code caters for errors for either:

1. the sheet name already existing
2. the sheet name being invalid (empty (ie ""), too long or invalid characters)

Code updates so sheet name is validated for length, and then by a `Regexp` for [Valid characters for Excel sheet names](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/451452/valid-characters-for-excel-sheet-names) before the sheet is created

If either 1 or 2 is true the user is re-prompted (with an additional try again message)

```
Public Sub CariSheet()
Dim SheetName As String
Dim bFinished As Boolean
Dim strMsg As String
Dim ws As Worksheet

Do While Not bFinished
    SheetName = InputBox("Pls enter the name of the sheet", strMsg, "Add Sheet")
    On Error Resume Next
    Set ws = Sheets(SheetName)
    On Error GoTo 0

    If ws Is Nothing Then
        Select Case Len(SheetName)
        Case 0
        strMsg = "Sheet name is blank"
        Case Is > 31
        strMsg = "Sheet name exceeds 31 characters"
        Case Else
            If ValidSheetName(SheetName) Then
                Set ws = Worksheets.Add(After:=Worksheets(Worksheets.Count))
                ws.Name = SheetName
            Else
                strMsg = "Sheet name has invalid characters"
            End If
        End Select
    Else
        strMsg = "Sheet exists"
        Set ws = Nothing
    End If
Loop

End Sub
```

*test for valid sheet name*

```
Function ValidSheetName(strIn As String) As Boolean
    Dim objRegex As Object
    Set objRegex = CreateObject("vbscript.regexp")
    objRegex.Pattern = "[\<\>\*\\\/\?|]"
    ValidSheetName = Not objRegex.test(strIn)
End Function
```

Comment: @brettdj wow thanks, but when i enter a blank, the msg box appear but a new sheet was made anyway..
if it doesn't bother you, how can i fix it..?
thanks for your help, i really appreciate it..

Comment: @brettdj thanks a lot your code is really specific thats a big help and thanks for the revision of the title that would help other who have similar problem to find this solution.

Comment: @AdityaNugroho No problem - well asked, and well done for staying active in your question. :)