# Complex VLOOKUP with dynamic sheet name

Tags: vba, excel, vlookup

I'm trying to perform a vlookup across multiple sheets in an elegant way, rather than with a vlookup nested in an IF function.

Column A has the account number and Column I has the manager responsible for that account. Each Manager has their own sheet. I was hoping to make vlookup look at a specific manager's sheet, find the account number in Column A, and return the info in Column K. I tried to use INDIRECT to make it do that:

```
=VLOOKUP($A2,INDIRECT($I2 & "!$A:$P"),11,FALSE)
```

With this code, I keep getting #REF instead of what is in Column K in the manager's sheet. How can I fix this?

Thanks!

Comment: Make sure the text in $I2 has no spaces or extra parts that may make the reference break.  Use Trim() - `=VLOOKUP(trim($A2),INDIRECT($I2 & "!$A:$P"),11,FALSE)`

Comment: I don't know what your data looks like, but keep in mind that vlookup only functions left to right. If your "lookup ID" is to the right of the value that you are looking up, your function will not work.

Comment: @user3578951, there are no leading or trailing spaces so I don't think trim would work

Comment: @Dr.Trey the first parameter for the VLOOKUP is in Column A, and I'm trying to return the info in Column K, so I should be ok with that. Thanks though!

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I can't see your spreadsheet but if your sheets are named after managers I am willing to bet that those sheet names have some kind of character( like space) that forces referencing sheets in single quotes.

Assuming that is correct simply change your formula to:

`=VLOOKUP($A2,INDIRECT("'" & $I2 & "'!$A:$P"),11,FALSE)`

Also you can diagnose this issue with "Evaluate Formula" located in "Formulas>Formula Auditing", in there step through all steps that this formula has, and note when does that error shows up.

Comment: You're correct in that there are spaces in the sheet name, didn't think of that! However, the code still isn't working for some reason. I'll keep playing with it and let you know if I can figure it out. Someone else recommended using trim, but there are no leading or trailing spaces, just spaces in between first and last name, so I think you're on the right track with single quotes

Comment: I know that this code works:  =VLOOKUP($A2,INDIRECT("'John Smith'" & "!$A:$P"),11,FALSE) I just need to make John Smith reference a cell value

Comment: So that being said you are getting #REF! error for all managers I assume, because if not then my next bet would be that there are some spelling differences between cells and sheet names, in which case user3578951's suggestion might be of help as an check for trailling spaces.

Comment: also were you able to check if it is the `INDIRECT` or `VLOOKUP` that throws an error?

Comment: It's the INDIRECT that is giving me an error. I know because the vlookup works fine when I put the name in single quotes and join it to "!$A:$P"

Comment: Ok I didn't catch that from your previous message, I'll try to think of what else might go wrong.

Comment: Check following question to see if your sheets don't break any of the follwoing rules. http://stackoverflow.com/questions/451452/valid-characters-for-excel-sheet-names

Comment: I've also tried using CONCATENATE(I2, "$A:$P) as the second parameter in the VLOOKUP function but with that I just get #VALUE!

Comment: could you give us maybe a little sample of the manager names that you have? maybe mix the first names with last name to maintain their privacy. It just sounds to me that their names are not valid for sheet names or something.

Comment: One suggestion - temporarily rename a spreadsheet to something like "THIS".  Then set the cell you want to point INDIRECT to do "THIS".  That should at least let you know if it's an error caused by punctuation (spaces, etc.) or if it's a formula issue.

Comment: Thanks all for the help! I found a workaround. I created a new column that used a formula to isolate the last word in Column I, which was, in this case, the last name of the Manager. All of the other sheets are titled with the last name of the Manager, so I directed the Indirect column to the new last name column instead of Column I