# '' is not a valid name. make sure that it does not include invalid characters or punctuation

Tags: excel, vb.net

Here is my connection string

```
  Dim connString As String = "Provider=Microsoft.ACE.OLEDB.12.0;Data Source=O:\[...].xlsx;Extended Properties='Excel 12.0 Xml;HDR=YES;'"
```

I dynamically extract the worksheet name straight out of the excel:

```
    Dim xlWorkSheet As Excel.Worksheet
    Dim xlApp As New Excel.Application
    xlApp.Workbooks.Open("O:[...].xlsx", 0, True)
    xlWorkSheet = CType(xlApp.Sheets(1), Excel.Worksheet)
    Dim sheetName As String = xlWorkSheet.Name

    Dim query As String = "SELECT [Part Number] FROM [" & sheetName & "$] WHERE [Sub-Category] = '-EEPROM'"
    Dim tempTable As New DataTable()
```

Then a classic OleDB transaction:

```
    Try ' OleDB transaction:
        Using co As New OleDbConnection(connString)
            Dim command As New OleDbCommand(query, co)

            ' Opens the connection
            co.Open()

            ' Perform the 1st query:
            Dim adapter As New OleDbDataAdapter(command)

            ' Fills in a table
            tempTable.Clear()
            adapter.Fill(tempTable)

            ' Disposes of objects
            adapter.Dispose()
        End Using

    Catch ex As Exception
        MsgBox("Error: " & ex.Message,, "Error getting the EEPROM match")
    End Try
```

Aaaand I get the following error:
'xxx' is not a valid name. Make sure that it does not include invalid characters or punctuation and that it is not too long.

xxx being the actual name of the worksheet, as seen in excel and retrieved through the excel object.

Edit: And this name is letters and spaces only, 13 characters long.

Slightly confused, and thanks for helping!

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Valid characters for Excel sheet names](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/451452/valid-characters-for-excel-sheet-names)

Comment: @ps2goat sheet name is letters + spaces only, 13 characters long.

Comment: Did you try replacing the variable _sheetname_ with a constant string for the sheet name as you see it in excel?

Comment: @Steve yes of course, and i used a variable afterwards to make sure it wasn't an error on my side

Comment: @pnuts the square brackets should account for that. also tried adding single quotes, without success: same error occurred.

Answer (score 0):

The problem may be in your linked excel. Try to rename "xxx" to name of your excel sheet.

Comment: As it’s currently written, your answer is unclear. Please [edit] to add additional details that will help others understand how this addresses the question asked. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).