# Create a new named sheet using a date

Tags: excel, vba

I am trying to create a new worksheet in excel vba using the following:

```
Option Explicit

Sub NewSheet()
    Dim T As Date, TabName As String
    T = Date
    TabName = "Progress " + CStr(T)
    ThisWorkbook.Sheets.Add(After:=Sheets("BiWeeklyProgress")).Name = TabName
    
End Sub
```

it is not working, and I cant find the problem? any help?

Comment: Mey be silly question but, is your Workbook Macro-Enabled?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You cannot use `/` characters in a sheet name, so format the date differently.

[Valid characters for Excel sheet names](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/451452/valid-characters-for-excel-sheet-names)

```
Option Explicit

Sub NewSheet()
    Dim T As Date, TabName As String
    T = Date
    TabName = "Progress " + Format(T, "mm.d.yyyy")
    ThisWorkbook.Sheets.Add(After:=Sheets("BiWeeklyProgress")).Name = TabName
    
End Sub
```

and for that matter... all you really need is:

```
Sub NewSheet()
    ThisWorkbook.Sheets.Add(After:=Sheets("BiWeeklyProgress")).Name = "Progress " + Format(Date, "mm.d.yyyy")
End Sub
```

The extra variables might come in handy for some other reason, but you do not need them.

With that said, you will also get an error if you run this more than once, because the sheet name will already exist, so you may want to add a check for that. This is when using a variable for the sheet name comes in handy, because you will be using it more than once.

```
Sub NewSheet()
    Dim TabName As String
    TabName = "Progress " + Format(Date, "mm.d.yyyy")
    If WorksheetExists(TabName) Then
      MsgBox TabName & " already exists"
      ' you can put whatever else you want here to handle this scenario
    Else
      ThisWorkbook.Sheets.Add(After:=Sheets("BiWeeklyProgress")).Name = TabName
    End If
End Sub

Function WorksheetExists(sName As String) As Boolean
    WorksheetExists = Evaluate("ISREF('" & sName & "'!A1)")
End Function
```

Comment: Hi, I already added a function to determine whether the sheet exist or not, so I delete it first and then create it again. 
`Function Sheet_Exists(WorkSheet_Name As String) As Boolean
Dim Work_sheet As Worksheet

Sheet_Exists = False

For Each Work_sheet In ThisWorkbook.Worksheets

    If Work_sheet.Name = WorkSheet_Name Then
        Sheet_Exists = True
    End If

Next

End Function
`

Comment: As long as it works, that's what matters. My `WorksheetEsists` function is just a much shorter/faster way of doing it, as it does not require looping.