# VBA Create a new sheet and then name it using todays date

Tags: excel, vba

I am trying to add a new sheet into excel then name it based on today's date.
I found the following code on a previous post: [Create a new named sheet using a date](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/65696095/create-a-new-named-sheet-using-a-date?newreg=1251e2597ed44490b522becb57b21462)

```
Sub NewSheet()
    Dim T As Date, TabName As String
    T = Date
    TabName = "Progress " + Format(T, "mm.d.yyyy")
    ThisWorkbook.Sheets.Add(After:=Sheets("BiWeeklyProgress")).Name = TabName
    
End Sub
```

This code works perfectly for any new workbook I create and apply it to, however when I apply it to the workbook that I need it for I receive the following error message:

"Compile error:

Wrong number of arguments or invalid property assignment"

I only receive this error when applying the code to my desired workbook. This workbook is connected to a Bloomberg terminal, could that be the issue? Please help!

Comment: Because you are using `ThisWorkbook`.

Comment: What exactly does "applying the code to my desired workbook" entail? The use of `ThisWorkbook` implies that the macro will only work as expected when present in a workbook that has a worksheet named "BiWeeklyProgress".

Comment: Consider separating creating the worksheet from naming it; by chaining the two operations you are 1) discarding the worksheet object reference, and 2) obscuring which part of the instruction is failing.

Comment: Thank you all for the comments. To answer your questions: @BigBen this is the exact code I am using. 2. I say my desired workbook because this code works perfectly in other files but not the file I need it to could this be because it is linked to a Bloomberg terminal?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If you're getting a compile error, then a guess:

```
TabName = "Progress " & VBA.Format(T, "mm.d.yyyy")
```

or shorter:

```
ActiveWorkbook.Sheets.Add(After:=Sheets("BiWeeklyProgress")).Name = "Progress " & _
   VBA.Format(Date, "mm.d.yyyy")
```

Comment: Someone somewhere shadowed the `Format` function from the `VBA` library ... shame on whoever it was :-)

Answer (score 0):

You're making it needlessly complex.
Try:

```
ActiveWorkbook.Sheets.Add(After:=Sheets("BiWeeklyProgress")).Name = "Progress " & _
   Format(Date, "mm.d.yyyy")
```

Comment: Thank you for the answer, I tried this code and having the same issue. It does in fact work for other workbooks, but not for the workbook I need it for (note that this one has a Bloomberg plugin). I am lost at this point.